# Custom Form disappears while dragging when it is placed in Second monitor(Negative Co-ordinates)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, operating-system

I have created custom form  which is inherited from MS Form and added some customization. The custom form disappears(location not updated) while dragging when it is placed in Second monitor (Location with Negative co-ordinate). This problem occurs only when disable option "Show Window contents while dragging"

[image]

Steps To produce problem.

1. Un check the "Show window contents while dragging-OFF".

2.Now place custom form in second monitor (location with negative co-ordinatinates).

3.Drag the window, now the form dis-appears

Suggest any solution to resolve this

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some *sizing logic* there that doesn't consider negative values when the position of the Form is (re-)calculated?

Comment: @Jimi Yes, i dont have sizing logic in my custom form, which logic i need to use to reslove.this problem

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this behavior. Did exactly what you said tho. My Win10 is build 18362 and does not have those ON/OFF in the settings (never had, btw).